# What is the shape of the C object corresponding to this TFLite output?

Tags: c, tensorflow-lite

I have a YOLOv5 trained model converted to .tflite format having used [this guide](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=yolov5+to+tflite&atb=v262-1&ia=web).

I use this code to print the input and output shape in python:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(
    # model_path="models/exported_resnet640.tflite")  # centernet_512x512 works correctly
    model_path="models/yolov5_working.tflite")  # centernet_512x512 works correctly

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print("======================================================")
print(input_details)
print("======================================================")
# print(output_details)
for detail in output_details:
    print(detail)
    print(" ")
```

and the output looks like this:

```
======================================================
[{'name': 'input_1', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 480, 480,   3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 480, 480,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
======================================================
{'name': 'Identity', 'index': 422, 'shape': array([    1, 14175,     9], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([    1, 14175,     9], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}
```

After invoking the interpreter after giving some input, I get an output looking like this:

```
Output:  [[[0.01191081 0.01366316 0.02800988 ... 0.1661754  0.31489396 0.4217688 ]
  [0.02396268 0.01650745 0.0442626  ... 0.24655405 0.35853994 0.2839473 ]
  [0.04218047 0.01613732 0.0548977  ... 0.13136038 0.25760946 0.5338376 ]
  ...
  [0.82626414 0.9669814  0.4534862  ... 0.18754318 0.11680853 0.18492043]
  [0.8983849  0.9680944  0.64181983 ... 0.19781056 0.16431764 0.16926363]
  [0.9657682  0.9869368  0.5452545  ... 0.13321301 0.12015155 0.15937251]]]
```

Using the Tensorflow Lite [c_api.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h), I am trying to get the same output in C, but I cannot understand how to create the object that get the data.

I have tried using a `float***` with size `1 * 14715 * 9 * sizeof(float)` and get the output like so:

```
  int number_of_detections = 14175;
  struct filedata o_boxes;
  float ***box_coords = (float ***)malloc(sizeof(float **) * 1);

  box_coords[0] = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * (int)number_of_detections);
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)number_of_detections; i++)
  {
    box_coords[0][i] = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), 9); // box has 9 coordinates
  }

  o_boxes.data = box_coords;
  o_boxes.size = 1 * (int)number_of_detections * 9 + 1;

  const TfLiteTensor *output_tensor_boxes =
      TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 0);
  TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor_boxes, o_boxes.data,
                           o_boxes.size * sizeof(float));

  box_coords = (float ***)&o_boxes.data;

  for (int i = 0; i < o_boxes.size; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      printf("%f ", box_coords[0][i][j]);
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

where `struct filedata` is a simple struct:

```
struct filedata
{
  void *data;
  size_t size;
};
```

The result is some garbage big floats:

```
39688651931648.000000 0.000000 39805756899328.000000 0.000000 39807166185472.000000 0.000000 39807367512064.000000 0.000000 39807568838656.000000
```

and after the first iteration I get a Segmentation Fault.

How should I create/allocate my float array to get my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the result comes all in one single line, so I have modified the code like so:

```
int number_of_detections = 14175;
  struct filedata o_boxes;

  float **box_coords = malloc(sizeof(float *) * number_of_detections);

  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_detections; i++)
  {
    box_coords[i] = calloc((9 + 1), sizeof(float)); // box has 9 coordinates, added 1 to be sure
  }

  o_boxes.data = (void *)box_coords;
  o_boxes.size = (number_of_detections * 9);

  const TfLiteTensor *output_tensor_boxes =
      TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 0);
  TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor_boxes, o_boxes.data,
                           o_boxes.size * sizeof(float));

  box_coords = (float **)&o_boxes.data;  // not entirely sure why we need & there

  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_detections; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      printf("%f ", box_coords[0][j + i * 9]);  // we know we have 9 coordinates, and every line is 9 floats away
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Works like a charm now!